# conditional from array or switch statement instead of input value using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi guys first of all my script is working perfectly but i have this little annoying problem i want to solve but i am not sure if its possible.

I have this form elements like, **select**, **datalist** and input types like **radio** and **checkbox** the way i code the conditional statement is that i rely on its value where my problem occurs cause what if i change the value later? i will have to change my code as well.

Example i have this radio input where users have to select which meal they want

```
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
  <div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio">
      <input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>
      Burger with fries
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label class="radio">
     <input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />
     Chicken with rice</label>
  </div>
```

and add value to whichever they select example if user selected "Burger with fries"

```
$('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev) {

  if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
    var meal = 20;
  } else {
    var meal = 30;
  }
  $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

});
```

now what i want is that instead of relying on the input value can i just use array, or is it too difficult or maybe you can propose an easier solution so that i dont have to manually edit the code whenever the input value is changed

thanks in advance here is my full script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
            var meal = 20;
        }
        else {
            var meal = 30;
        }

        $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:radio[name="drinks-123"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
            var drinks = 1;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
            var drinks = 1.20;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
            var drinks = 2;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
            var drinks = 1.75;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
            var drinks = 3;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
            var drinks = 1.25;
        }
        else {
            var drinks = 0;
        }

        $('#drinks').text((drinks).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });


    $('input:radio[name="extras-781"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
            var extras = 10;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
            var extras = 5;
        }
        else {
            var extras = 0;
        }
        $('#extras').text((extras).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });

    $('textarea[name="spoon-112"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var spoon = spoon*.25;
        $("#spoon").text(spoon).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:text[name="fork-143"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var fork = fork*.5;
        $("#fork").text(fork).trigger('change');
    });



    $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
        var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
            return acc + +val.textContent   ;
        }, 0);
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
<div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
<br />
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: drinks</h2>
<div class="drinks-123-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Coke" /> Coke
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Water" /> Water
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="No drinks-123" /> No drinks-123
</div>

<h2>Question 3: extras</h2>
<div class="drinks-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Rice" /> Rice
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoon?</h2>
<div class="spoon-wrapper">
    <textarea name="spoon-112" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra fork?</h2>
<div class="fork-wrapper">
    <input name="fork-143" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="price-wrapper">
    <b>meal:</b> <span id="meal"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>drinks:</b> <span id="drinks"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>extras:</b> <span id="extras"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>spoon:</b> <span id="spoon"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>fork:</b> <span id="fork"></span>
</div>

<div class="total-wrapper">
    <h3>
        <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `<input type="number" ... />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data type which utilizes `[key,value]` pair. I think it's suitable for your case, assuming there won't be any duplicate key.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mealMap = new Map();
    mealMap.set("Burger with fries", 20);
    mealMap.set("Chicken with rice", 30);
    $('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){
        var meal = mealMap.get($(this).val());
        $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

    });
});
```

EDIT:

According to what you want, then it can only depend on the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) of the `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.meal-wrapper input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){
    if ($( '.meal-wrapper input:radio[name="meal-356"]' ).index( this ) == 0) {
      var meal = 20;   
    } else if ($( '.meal-wrapper input:radio[name="meal-356"]' ).index( this ) == 1) {
      var meal = 30;
    }
    $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
<div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
<br />
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the input but i am trying to avoid typing the values which are burger with fries so i can change it anytime in the future without changing the jquery codes

Comment: @cryptohustla I think that cannot be done, unless you define the value such as `20`, `30` as the property of each corresponding `input`. However, I won't recommend that due to security issue, unless you did another check on the back-end. Do you do that?

Comment: @cryptohustla there is a flaw in the logic, think about it again. If you assume the order of the item are fixed then you can just use [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: you know what.. its awesome did some experiment and it works perfectly :D

Comment: @cryptohustla What did you do?

Comment: i did use your advise using index :D